# Pagination reverts back to no. 1 when clicked on back button

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, material-ui, pagination

I am creating a Pagination in ReactJS, and redirecting to other page from the pagination page. If I am on page 4 of pagination and from page 4, I go to some other page and when I come back to the previous page, I should be on page 4 of pagination. But instead pagination starts again from 1 after pressing back button. How do I solve it ??

Pagination.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Pagination } from '@mui/material';

const CustomPagination = (props) => {

  const handlePageChange = (event, page) => {
    props.setPage(page);
  }

  return (
    <Pagination 
    count = {10}
    onChange = { handlePageChange}
    color = "primary"
    size='large'
    />
  )
}

export default CustomPagination
```

Home.js

```
const [page, setPage] = useState(1);

useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [page])
```

How can I solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused because your page is fully rerendered when you move back and the `page` value is set to 1:
`const [page, setPage] = useState(1);`

You can store page in the query:
`/your-route?page=4`

Something like this should work for Next.js:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
...

const router = useRouter();
const { page } = router.query;

const [page, setPage] = useState(page || 1);
```